# Android 6.0 sticky service killed by PgedBinderListener on Huawei P9

Tags: android, service, android-6.0-marshmallow, huawei-mobile-services

I have a very specific problem on one type of device. The app I'm working on doesn't have any problems on any of the devices with the exception of Huawei P9.

The app starts a service, which is supposed to work in background, however, on that one device, the service is being killed when device is locked. I tracked down the problem to this:

```
09-20 14:31:14.799 1854-1878/? I/PgedBinderListener: kstate callback type:8 value1=2656 value2=KILLED
```

I have no idea what might be the cause. The only suspicious thing I'm seeing in the log is error supposedly generated by Keyguard. The fact that it's Huawei related error and fact that issue only presents itself on a Huawei device seems to suggest a connection. Here is the error:

```
09-20 14:31:10.804 1364-1584/? I/KeyguardService: KGSvcCall onStartedGoingToSleep. 2
09-20 14:31:10.837 1902-1902/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher onStop()
09-20 14:31:10.841 1902-1912/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher.LauncherProvider  begin check permission at checkPermission
09-20 14:31:10.843 1902-1912/? W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider from pid=1364, uid=10029 requires com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS: uid 10029 does not have com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
09-20 14:31:10.843 1902-1912/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1599)
09-20 14:31:10.843 1902-1912/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforcePermission(ContextImpl.java:1612)
09-20 14:31:10.843 1902-1912/? W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforcePermission(ContextWrapper.java:664)
09-20 14:31:10.843 1902-1912/? W/System.err:     at com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider.checkPermission(LauncherProvider.java:1615)
09-20 14:31:10.843 1902-1912/? W/System.err:     at com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider.call(LauncherProvider.java:1854)
09-20 14:31:10.843 1902-1912/? W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:398)
09-20 14:31:10.843 1902-1912/? W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:283)
09-20 14:31:10.843 1902-1912/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
09-20 14:31:10.844 1902-1912/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider from pid=1364, uid=10029 requires com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS: uid 10029 does not have com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
                                                    at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1599)
                                                    at android.app.ContextImpl.enforcePermission(ContextImpl.java:1612)
                                                    at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforcePermission(ContextWrapper.java:664)
                                                    at com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider.checkPermission(LauncherProvider.java:1615)
                                                    at com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider.call(LauncherProvider.java:1854)
                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:398)
                                                    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:283)
                                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
09-20 14:31:10.845 1364-1650/? E/LauncherInteractiveUtil: Call launcher evnt fail. lock=true
                                                          java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider from pid=1364, uid=10029 requires com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS: uid 10029 does not have com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1602)
                                                              at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                              at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                              at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
                                                              at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:437)
                                                              at com.huawei.keyguard.support.LauncherInteractiveUtil$Caller.run(LauncherInteractiveUtil.java:59)
                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I did try to add com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS permission to the manifest, however it did not make any difference, since error logged seems to be caused by Keyguard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was writing the question I stumbled upon the answer.

On Huawei you have to add the app to Protected Apps in Battery Management in order to prevent the service from being killed. User can be informed about that upon perforing the check:
"huawei".equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)
Apparently there is no way to check if the app is already enabled there.